# viewWithTag not loading text unto view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function includes the following line:

```
var chanceLabel : UILabel? = self.view.viewWithTag(uni_tag) as? UILabel
```

My storyboard is structured as such where the TableViewController is a subview of a view controller.

Each of the chance labels are tagged, such that if one's GPA is of certain level, it would return a string to show the chance of getting in for each university. You can see for example for Berkeley, it's "Not likely"

[image: storyboard structure]

The goal is to have the labels dynamically updated depending on the GPA. I placed the function within 'viewDidAppear', and all it does is clear the label - and that's only for the universities that are above the fold - even though I feed strings into it as such:

```
chanceLabel?.text = "High"
```

I'm using XCode 6.1.1, and cannot update it at the moment as this is part of my university project. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: try printing chanceLabel?.text in console to see are you getting any view from self.view.viewWithTag(uni_tag) correctly or not.

Comment: @MAbdulSami The log showed the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxkyoq90ykk8u8v/Screenshot%202015-06-20%2016.29.51.png?dl=0 You can see some are nil, and some have values, which is quite...interesting

Comment: @Sulthan The question is why when I do something like this - theLabel?.text = "High" - it won't show on the tableviewcontroller

Comment: are you sure the label is tagged correctly? are you sure you are using the correct tag? are you sure there is not another view with the same tag? By the way, tags are usually the easiest thing to break - using outlets generally leads to much better code.

Comment: @Sulthan I retried based on your suggestion. Changed the tags, experimented with different tags and views, and it replicates the same results that I shared with MAbdulSami : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxkyoq90ykk8u8v/Screenshot%202015-06-20%2016.29.51.png?dl=0

Some have values, but some return nil

Comment: are you setting these tags programatically?

Comment: @MAbdulSami No, they were added in the view manually and are not automatically generated

Comment: @MAbdulSami I can change the text for items above the fold now with viewDidAppear, but I still can't edit items below the fold (what isn't visible to the screen on load). Is there a property I can use to handle that?

Comment: @MAbdulSami Just solved it with override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by placing the labeling into:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

The reason it failed is that because the TableViewController was a subview of the main view (View Controller), and utilizing "viewDidAppear" only focuses the main view's frame. However, the viewDidLayoutSubviews was the better solution given the storyboard design.

Answer (score 1):

table cells are loaded dynamically based on the data and delegates. On top of that, lazy loading doesn't let anything load until called. I think your answer is a need to read the views and view controller programming guide so you understand why your views were nil. The code would work perfectly if the tableView loaded every view, but you did not wait for it and this is not how to add data to a table.

Apple will crash your program if you alter visual states instead of using delegates inside a table, move a cell too low or too high via centerpoint to find this out.

I'm somewhat harsh here, I know, but I don't want you to run around thinking Apple broke when it wasn't them, causes code smells, makes it hard for you in the future.